# Kubectl: Access kubernetes cluster using route53 private hosted zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-route53, kubectl, kops

I stared my kubernetes cluster on AWS EC2 with kops using a private hosted zone in route53. Now when I do something like `kubectl get nodes`, the cli says that it can't connect to `api.kops.test.com` as it is unable to resolve it. So I fixed this issue by manually adding `api.kops.test.com` and its corresponding public IP (got through record sets) mapping in `/etc/hosts` file.

I wanted to know if there is a cleaner way to do this (without modifying the system-wide `/etc/hosts` file), maybe programmatically or through the cli itself.

Comment: Do you have a corporate DNS zone, such as `company.com` where you could add the aforementioned public-ip as an `A` record, and then add `api.kops.company.com` as a SAN in the x509 cert?

Answer (score 1):

Pragmatically speaking, I would add the public IP as a `IP` SAN to the master's x509 cert, and then just use the public IP in your kubeconfig. Either that, or the DNS record *not* in the private route53 zone.

You are in a situation where you purposefully made things private, so now they are.

---

Another option, depending on whether it would be worth the effort, is to use a VPN server in your VPC and then connect your machine to EC2 where the VPN connection can add the EC2 DNS servers to your machine's config as a side-effect of connecting. Our corporate Cisco AnyConnect client does something very similar to that.